# Getting a substring out of a string raises a TypeError

Tags: python

Update: The problem was caused by a typo, and therefore shouldn't be reproduced.

I want to make a script which finds a number N which can be found in Pi starting from the N-th digit.

Running this code (where pi is a string in the form "31415926..."):

```
for i in range(len(pi)):
  if i == pi[i-1,i+len(str(i))]:
    print(i)
```

Brings up this error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: `,` isn't `:`. (Closing as typo.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
for i in range(len(pi)):
  if str(i + 1) == pi[i: i+len(str(i + 1))]:
    print(i + 1)
```

You made two mistakes:

1. Slice notation uses `:`, not `,`
2. `range` starts counting from `0`, not `1`. So you would have started index `-1`, instead of the desired index of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your code to the following;

```
for i in range(len(pi)):
if str(i) == pi[i-1:i-1+len(str(i))]:
    print(i)
```

In `Python`, you use the `:` rather than `,` to slice a string.

`i` must be converted to a string. The slice you make does not make it an integer. It keeps its string properties.

The slice starts a `i-1`. This leaves out the `0`. `i-1+len(str(i))]` was just accommodated to fit the slice.

Comment: @TomerGan I didn't see that for some reason.